# Error with my RoleManager in the context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm tryng customizing my application. But I have some problems when I try to create the follow role:

```
private void createRolesandUsers()
{
    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
    var UserManager = new KnockdocUserManager(new UserStore<Usuario, Papel, int, Login, UsuarioPapel, Claim>(context));

    if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
    {
        //create Admin Role First
        var role = new IdentityRole();
        role.Name = "Admin";
        roleManager.Create(role);
```

Error:

> The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

That is my appcontext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext<Usuario, Papel, int, Login, UsuarioPapel, Claim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("BD_KnockdocContext")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Map Entities to their tables.
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().ToTable("Usuario");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Papel>().ToTable("Papel");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Claim>().ToTable("Claim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Login>().ToTable("Login");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UsuarioPapel>().ToTable("UsuarioPapel");

        // Set AutoIncrement-Properties
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Claim>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Papel>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        // Override some column mappings that do not match our default
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(r => r.UserName).HasColumnName("Login");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(r => r.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("Password");
    }
}
```

What a did wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same problem but with `.edmx` model. I should update the model and rebuild few times the project, magically it starts.